# Error message "gradlew: command not found"

Tags: java, linux, gradle, installation

I am working on a Java project with [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:using_wrapper) (`gradlew`). I use Ubuntu Linux as my OS. When I run "gradle" it runs, and gives me information. But when I run "gradlew", it outputs as:

> No command 'gradlew' found, did you mean: 
> Command 'gradle' from package 'gradle' (universe) 
> gradlew: command not found"

I did my research, I have the JDK, and I did `sudo apt-get install gradle`. How can I fix it?

The error is:

```
gradlew clean jpackage
```

Output:

```
bash: gradlew: command not found...
```

Comment: Run `./gradlew`. It isn't on your path but is an executable that is present in the root directory of the project you checkout.

Comment: Read the documentation on the gradle wrapper, https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html.

Comment: Using Windows: Solve my problem running command prompt as administrator

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The Gradle wrapper needs to be built. Try running `gradle wrapper --gradle-version 2.13`.

Remember to change 2.13 to your Gradle version number. After running this command, you should see new scripts added to your project folder. You should be able to run the wrapper with `./gradlew build` to build your code.

Please refer to this guide for more information: *[Building Java Projects with Gradle](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/)*

Answer (score 363):

#### Linux and macOS

As noted in the comments, just running

```
./gradlew
```

worked for me. Adding the `./` tells it to look in the current directory since it isn't in the path.

If it stills doesn't work, run (*as commented by Fadi*)

```
chmod +x gradlew
```

And then try again

#### Windows PowerShell

```
.\gradlew
```

Comment: first try "chmod +x gradlew" and then "./gradlew" if not working

Comment: for macOS catalina, "sudo bash ./gradlew" works for me

Comment: no one can even assume that there might be no gradlew at the address ./

Comment: chmod +x gradlew has worked for me

Comment: To those who are confused about the `chmod +x ./gradlew`, the `chmod +x` part just makes the `./gradlew` executable. You need to use this, just trying with `sudo` won't work.

Answer (score 81):

Running this Bash command works for me by running `chmod 755 gradlew` as sometimes file properties changed upon moving from one OS to another (Windows, Linux and Mac).

Comment: Your solution works, just to clarify, this command allows for execution file as a program (on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Comment: [chmod 755](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-755/) = (chmod a+rwx,g-w,o-w) sets permissions so that, (U)ser / owner can read, can write and can execute. (G)roup can read, can't write and can execute. ***(O)thers*** can read, can't write and can ***execute***.

Answer (score 48):

If you are using Mac, try giving root access to *gradlew* by doing:

```
chmod +x ./gradlew
```

Answer (score 33):

From Mac,

Nothing is working except the following command:

```
chmod 777 gradlew
```

Then

```
./gradlew
```

Comment: gradlew needs permission on linux/mac, working for me after chmod 777 gradlew in root of my project.

Comment: 'chmod 777' makes gradlew world writable.  This is a major security issue.  Use 'chmod 555' instead.

Comment: I'd recommend chmod 755 (-rwxr-xr-x). over 777

Comment: [chmod 777](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-777/): (chmod a+rwx) sets permissions so that, (U)ser / owner can read, can write and can execute. (G)roup can read, can write and can execute. ***(O)thers can read, can write and can execute***.

Comment: [chmod 555](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-555/): (chmod a+rwx,u-w,g-w,o-w) sets permissions so that, (U)ser / owner can read, can't write and can execute. (G)roup can read, can't write and can execute. (O)thers can read, can't write and can execute.

Comment: [chmod 755](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-755/): (chmod a+rwx,g-w,o-w) sets permissions so that, (U)ser / owner can read, can write and can execute. (G)roup can read, can't write and can execute. (O)thers can read, can't write and can execute.

Answer (score 29):

The same problem occurs to me...

I check the file wrx permissions with:

`$ls -l ./gradlew` -> -rw-rw-r-- (no execute permission)

So I use command `$chmod +x ./gradlew` and this problem is solved.

Answer (score 21):

In addition to [Suragch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700798/error-message-gradlew-command-not-found/43936928#43936928):

**Linux and macOS**

`./gradlew clean`

**Windows PowerShell**

`.\gradlew clean`

**Windows cmd**

`gradlew clean`

Comment: Thanks! after hours of lurking from macos environment, this fixed: ./gradlew clean

Answer (score 12):

You must have the Gradle wrapper available locally before using *gradlew*. To construct that

```bash
gradle wrapper # --gradle-version v.xy
```

Optionally, pass the Gradle version explicitly. This step produces the *gradlew* binary. And then you should be able to

```bash
./gradlew build
```

Comment: zsh: command not found: gradle

Answer (score 7):

For [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) (Linux) users:

Doing `bash ./gradlew build` works, but `./gradlew build` does not work.

For me, the issue was it was on the [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) file system, and Linux does not let you execute a script from NTFS.

Try moving the code from NTFS to a Linux partition. Then `./gradlew build` should work.

Comment: Works for RedHat 7 too

Comment: Pop_OS! here, worked. Though my filesystem is default ext4

Comment: Re *"Linux does not let you execute a script from NTFS."*: Why not? Isn't it only a question of permissions (or how the partition is mounted)? What is special about NTFS?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Visual Studio Code with Flutter, you should find it in your app folder, under the *android* folder:

C:\myappFolder\android

You can run this in the terminal:

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

Comment: this was the case for me

Answer (score 4):

The first thing is you need to run the gradle task that you mentioned for this wrapper. Example:

`gradle wrapper`

After running this command, check your directory for the *gradlew* *and gradlew.bat* files. *gradlew* is the shell script file, and it can be used in Linux and macOS. *gradlew.bat* is the batch file for the Windows OS. Then run,

`./gradlew build` (Linux and Mac). It will work.

Answer (score 2):

Issue: Couldn't find gradlew at path jenkins

In my case, within the Jenkins [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) for flutter project, I have to first run the `flutter build` app command, and then it automatically generated a *gradlew* file. And the above issue is resolved.

I put this command in my Jenkins file:

```
flutter build apk
```

Answer (score 2):

In a Flutter project, don't forget to go to 'android' folder with 'cd android'.
Then you can run a command like './gradlew build' or './gradlew clean' on it (macOS).

Answer (score 1):

If the answer marked as correct does not work, it is because you need to identify yourself as a super user.

```
sudo gradle wrapper --gradle-version 2.13
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, but after some tries I found
it was happening because I was trying to create build in [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway),
instead of CMD with system administrator access.

If you *create build* with a command prompt, run as administrator. Then the build will get created.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `gradlew assembleRelease`, use `./gradlew assembleRelease`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run this command for a Flutter app, then go to the *android* folder first by *cd android*. And then use the command, and it should work.

```
cd android
./gradlew signingReport
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) and in Windows in the terminal I type:

`gradlew.bat run`

It is working for me.

Comment: Windows is *different*. For some reason, it always resolves executables in `.` as if it is in the path, even when it is very clearly not in the path.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do [`dos2unix *`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) in my current folder to make it work.

Answer (score -2):

#### Ubuntu

Error:

> Command 'gradlew' not found, did you mean: 
> command 'gradle' from snap gradle (7.2) 
> command 'gradle' from deb gradle (4.4.1-13) 
> See 'snap info ' for additional versions.

Use this command:

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).