# Why Android Studio doesn't run gradle?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem that I can not solve. When compiling, throw the following

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
Exit code 1 from:
C:\Users\userName\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app1\android\gradlew.bat
app:properties:
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file
```

'C:\Users\userName\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app1\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
> Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
Searched in the following
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

I tried to do what he says (I do not know if I did it right), but I did not solve.

How can I solve?

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: What does running `./gradlew build --info` in the terminal (in android studio) say?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [couldn't locate lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar for flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945041/couldnt-locate-lint-gradle-api-26-1-2-jar-for-flutter-project)

Comment: "." no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
Sorry for the spanish...

Comment: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42468842/1008011): run `chmod 777 gradlew` before running `./gradlew build --info`.

Comment: No sir, I write in Android Studio Terminal this code, but it doesn't work. It say the same "it is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: Have you taken a look at the "possible duplicate" link above? Does it provide a solution to the issue in your question?

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I solved gradle's problem with this link. Thanks. Now I have a problem with emulator.. It crashes... I'm unistalling android studio and I will install...

Comment: THANKS. I solved with this link and unistalling and installing again Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem in the current flutter version.
It has already been [reported](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/23397) to flutter, it should be fixed in the next release.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53133615/5483868) is the workaround that I answered in another post.