# Gradle : gradlew expecting in

Tags: gradle, gradlew

i am facing this issue

```
sparsh610@DESKTOP-551C51M:/mnt/e/xxxxxxxxx$ ./gradlew mm
: not found2: ./gradlew:
: not found8: ./gradlew:
./gradlew: 52: ./gradlew: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")
```

i verified that my system has gradle installed and with all the read write access.

any specific reason for this error ?

Already checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700798/gradlew-command-not-found)

Comment: You should post your build.gradle file.

Comment: It's a problem related to git and conversion between Windows and Unix endlines, see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2906

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Its simply a difference between UNIX and windows handling end of line character, so easy to solve just type `sed -i.bak 's/\r$//' gradlew` this will replace the carriage return. With the option -i, the file will be edited in-place, and the original file will be backed up as gradlew.bak

Comment: ... or just use Notepad++ to do a conversion, anyway - thanks so much!

Comment: Can you elaborate more each syntax? It works for me but I have no idea why...

Comment: I noticed that bash has some issues when lines terminate with \r\n instead of \n. Bash tries to interpret \r as a char belonging to the command, causing errors that are very difficult to understand.