# 'gradlew' is not recognized error in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter

please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwMsR.png)

gradlew' is not recognized

gradlew signingReport
or
./gradlew signingReport

its not working
please help

im in the right directry.

keytool -list -v 
-alias  -keystore

it also not working .
keytool is not recognized.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uylAp.png)

i want to get SHA certificate

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO and Android development.

As I can see in your screenshot you are using PowerShell, not CMD; there's a `PS` at the start of each line.

In PS to call a file in the current directory you need to prefix it with `./`, where the dot represents the current directory, and followed by the complete filename. Thus, in this case you need to type `./gradlew.bat signingReport`. From the screenshot it isn't clear if `gradlew.bat` is indeed in the current folder though.

The same goes for `keytool.exe`, which is most likely not in the same folder as `gradlew.bat`.

In any case be sure you autocomplete the files you are calling by pressing the Tab key; for example, type `gradl` and press the Tab key multiple times till you reach the file you are looking for. This is the best way to avoid typos.

###### Sidenote

This problem has nothing to do with Android, Flutter, Firebase or SHA. Please be sure to correctly tag your questions in order to get the best possible answer. In this case, PowerShell is more fitting.

Comment: not working Brother.

Comment: Mind doing an `ls` and posting the results here?

Comment: I want to get SHA Certificate for my flutter project

Answer (score 0):

You don't have Gradle wrapper (executable) in your project directory. It is not an error from Android Studio. You need to add wrapper for your project ([gradlew command not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700798/gradlew-command-not-found)) and then run it from current directory as `./gradlew` because when you are calling `gradle` it search it globally, not in current folder.

Comment: i tried this comand ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=7.6 --distribution-type=bin and ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=7.6 .  same error gradlew is not recognized

Comment: Did you tried to open `android` folder from Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `gradlew` file inside android folder, then run

if android project

```
- clean project
- rebuild project
```

if flutter project

```
- flutter clean
- flutter pub get
```