# command not found: gradlew

Tags: android, react-native, gradlew

A problem for which I looked for solutions on the net but despite everything the problem resisted. So finally here is how I solved.
I hope this can help someone in the future

Instead of `gradlew clean`, You just have to do it like this: `./gradlew clean`

1. `cd android`
2. `./gradlew clean`
3. `cd ..`
4. `npx react-native run-android`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gradlew command not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700798/gradlew-command-not-found)

Comment: Hey @nayoi. Your post is not really a question, is it? Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700798/gradlew-command-not-found

Comment: Yes thanks you @longi your suggested answer resolve the problem too. Thanks:)